# Change a NSURL's scheme

Tags: ios

Is there an easy way to change the scheme of a `NSURL`? I do realize that `NSURL` is immutable. My goal is to change the scheme of an URL to "https" if the `Security.framework` is linked, and "http" if the framework is not linked. I do know how to detect if the framework is linked.

This code works wonderfully if the URL has no parameters (such as "?param1=foo&param2=bar"):

```
+(NSURL*)adjustURL:(NSURL*)inURL toSecureConnection:(BOOL)inUseSecure {
    if ( inUseSecure ) {
        return [[[NSURL alloc] initWithScheme:@"https" host:[inURL host] path:[inURL path]] autorelease];
    }
    else {
        return [[[NSURL alloc] initWithScheme:@"http" host:[inURL host] path:[inURL path]] autorelease];
    }    
}
```

But if the URL does have parameters, `[inURL path]` drops them.

Any suggestions short of parsing the URL string myself (which I can do but I want to try not doing)? I do what to be able to pass URLs with either http or https to this method.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

#### Updated answer

`NSURLComponents` is your friend here. You can use it to swap out the `http` scheme for `https`. The only caveat is `NSURLComponents` uses RFC 3986 whereas `NSURL` uses the older RFCs 1738 and 1808, so there is some behavior differences in edge cases, but you're extremely unlikely to hit those cases (and `NSURLComponents` has the better behavior anyway).

```objc
NSURLComponents *components = [NSURLComponents componentsWithURL:url resolvingAgainstBaseURL:YES];
components.scheme = inUseSecure ? @"https" : @"http";
return components.URL;
```

---

#### Original answer

Why not just do a bit of string manipulation?

```objc
NSString *str = [url absoluteString];
NSInteger colon = [str rangeOfString:@":"].location;
if (colon != NSNotFound) { // wtf how would it be missing
    str = [str substringFromIndex:colon]; // strip off existing scheme
    if (inUseSecure) {
        str = [@"https" stringByAppendingString:str];
    } else {
        str = [@"http" stringByAppendingString:str];
    }
}
return [NSURL URLWithString:str];
```

Comment: Yeah, this is not what I wanted to do, but considering the interface of `NSURL`, it does seem the most appropriate.

Answer (score 29):

If you are using iOS 7 and later, you can use `NSURLComponents`, as show [here](http://joris.kluivers.nl/blog/2013/10/17/nsurlcomponents/)

```
NSURLComponents *components = [NSURLComponents new];
components.scheme = @"http";
components.host = @"joris.kluivers.nl";
components.path = @"/blog/2013/10/17/nsurlcomponents/";

NSURL *url = [components URL];
// url now equals:
// http://joris.kluivers.nl/blog/2013/10/17/nsurlcomponents/
```

Comment: I would recommend using
NSURLComponents *components = [NSURLComponents componentsWithURL:URL resolvingAgainstBaseURL:NO];

Answer (score 5):

**Swift5**

```
extension URL {
    func settingScheme(_ value: String) -> URL {
    let components = NSURLComponents.init(url: self, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: true)
    components?.scheme = value
    return (components?.url!)!
}
```

}

**Usage**

```
if nil == url.scheme { url = url.settingScheme("file") }
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps using the `resourceSpecifier` would help:

```
return [[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https:%@", [inURL resourceSpecifier]]]];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *newUrlString =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://%@%@", 
                          inURL.host, inURL.path];
if (inURL.query) {
    newUrlString = [newUrlString stringByAppendingFormat:@"?%@", inURL.query];
}
return [NSURL URLWithString:newUrl];
```

[NOTE]
Code related to port and other fields handling are removal for simplicity.

Comment: Other fields are missing, for example, "fragment" and "port". (ref: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt)

Comment: @HKTonyLee I know that. It's not a general url reconstruction. Port and fragment are missing in the question either. Just to tell him url.query is what he want.

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this, using a variable [`resourceSpecifier`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurl/1415309-resourcespecifier) in NSURL

**SWIFT**

```
var resourceSpecifier: String? { get }
```

**OBJECTIVE-C**

```
@property(readonly, copy) NSString *resourceSpecifier Discussion
```

This property contains the resource specifier. For example, in the URL http://www.example.com/index.html?key1=value1#jumplink, the resource specifier is //www.example.com/index.html?key1=value1#jumplink (everything after the colon).

```
  -(NSURL*) URLByReplacingScheme
    {
        NSString *newUrlString = kHttpsScheme;

        if([self.scheme isEqualToString:kEmbeddedScheme])
            newUrlString = kHttpScheme;

        newUrlString = [newUrlString stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@":%@", self.resourceSpecifier]];

        return [NSURL URLWithString:newUrlString];
    }
```

Comment: This method causes you to loose any URL parameters that be in the URL. That is, anything after the `?` or `#`

Comment: can you give an example?

Comment: if tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14393016/change-a-nsurls-scheme/26422712#comment41652927_26422712 and it returns https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14393016/change-a-nsurls-scheme/26422712#comment41652927_26422712